# Fixed points free permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

How to generate a list of fixpoint free permutations of n elements in mathematica?

Answer (score 5):

Here a brute force method.

```
n = 4;
perms = Permutations[Range[n]];
Pick[perms, Unitize[Min[Abs[# - Range[n]]] & /@ perms], 1]
```

> {{2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 1, 
>     2}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 5):

```
With[{n = 4},
  Select[Permutations[Range[n]], Length[PermutationSupport[#]] == n &]]
```

> {{2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

The fraction of permutations satisfying this condition is $1/e$ as $n\to\infty$, so the above code is not very wasteful.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the hints.